# How to add some word to username in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am the administrator in my website. When I register a new user, I want to add my username to new username. Such as:

my username: manager

new username: test

result: manager_test

I want to validate RESULT. I used **beforevalidate()** and add my username in it:

```
protected function beforeValidate()
{
    $this->username = Yii::app()->user->name.'_'.$this->username;
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

but something that stored to database is: manager_manager_manager_test.
In fact my program call beforevalidate in 3 times.

What shall I do? I want to read beforevalidate function once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether a new record to add a prefix when you create and use the "beforesave" for this.

```
public function beforeSave(){
    parent::beforeSave();
    if($this->isNewRecord())
        $this->username = Yii::app()->user->name.'_'.$this->username;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use your suggestion but I have a problem. when I entire a duplicate username, I can't handle my error and I see apge with below error:
`CDbException

خطای CDbCommand در اجرای SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'demo_ITC3' for key 'username'.`

Comment: You can specify custom validation. Add in the model function:
public function checkUsername($attribute, $params)
{
    $userModel = User::model()->find('username=:username', array(':username'=>Yii::app()->user->name.'_'.$this->username)); 
    if(!is_null($userModel)){
        $this->addError(attribute, "User with same name is exists");
    }
}

and add in rules array this rule:
array('username', 'checkUsername'),

Answer (score 0):

```
if(end(explode('_',Yii::app()->user->name)) != $this->username){
    $this->username = Yii::app()->user->name.'_'.$this->username;
}
return parent::beforeValidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it in before save? What is the point in validating something that you know you are adding, just let validate without anything and add what you want in beforeSave.